Trying to receive data sent by Xiao ESP32S3 & MPU6050 using Bleak library
This is the code that sends the data. Written in Arduino IDE
`#include "LSM6DS3.h"
#include "Wire.h"
#include <ArduinoBLE.h> // Include the Bluetooth library
#include <Adafruit_MPU6050.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>

Adafruit_MPU6050 mpu;

BLEService sensorService("b8b4e50d-f686-4757-918a-fcd2292782de"); // Define a service for IMU data
BLECharacteristic accelCharacteristic("85212279-0d50-4ca0-9a7e-730bdebf8e74", BLERead | BLENotify, 30); // Characteristic for accelerometer data
BLECharacteristic gyroCharacteristic("8c49379f-1cc9-46cc-94c3-38e12ef8e177", BLERead | BLENotify, 30); // Characteristic for gyroscope data


//LSM6DS3 myIMU(I2C_MODE, 0x6A);    //I2C device address 0x6A

    void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial);

    if (!BLE.begin()) {
        Serial.println("Failed to initialize BLE!");
        while (1);
    }

    BLE.setLocalName("NRF52840");
    BLE.setAdvertisedService(sensorService);
    sensorService.addCharacteristic(accelCharacteristic);
    sensorService.addCharacteristic(gyroCharacteristic);
    
    BLE.addService(sensorService);
    BLE.advertise();

  Serial.println("Adafruit MPU6050 test!");

  // Try to initialize!
  if (!mpu.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to find MPU6050 chip");
    while (1) {
      delay(10);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("MPU6050 Found!");

  mpu.setAccelerometerRange(MPU6050_RANGE_8_G);
  Serial.print("Accelerometer range set to: ");
  switch (mpu.getAccelerometerRange()) {
  case MPU6050_RANGE_2_G:
    Serial.println("+-2G");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_4_G:
    Serial.println("+-4G");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_8_G:
    Serial.println("+-8G");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_16_G:
    Serial.println("+-16G");
    break;
  }
  mpu.setGyroRange(MPU6050_RANGE_500_DEG);
  Serial.print("Gyro range set to: ");
  switch (mpu.getGyroRange()) {
  case MPU6050_RANGE_250_DEG:
    Serial.println("+- 250 deg/s");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_500_DEG:
    Serial.println("+- 500 deg/s");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_1000_DEG:
    Serial.println("+- 1000 deg/s");
    break;
  case MPU6050_RANGE_2000_DEG:
    Serial.println("+- 2000 deg/s");
    break;
  }

  mpu.setFilterBandwidth(MPU6050_BAND_21_HZ);
  Serial.print("Filter bandwidth set to: ");
  switch (mpu.getFilterBandwidth()) {
  case MPU6050_BAND_260_HZ:
    Serial.println("260 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_184_HZ:
    Serial.println("184 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_94_HZ:
    Serial.println("94 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_44_HZ:
    Serial.println("44 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_21_HZ:
    Serial.println("21 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_10_HZ:
    Serial.println("10 Hz");
    break;
  case MPU6050_BAND_5_HZ:
    Serial.println("5 Hz");
    break;
  }

  Serial.println("");
  delay(100);
}



void loop() {

  sensors_event_t a, g, temp;
  mpu.getEvent(&a, &g, &temp);

  /* Print out the values */
  Serial.print("Acceleration X: ");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.x);
  Serial.print(", Y: ");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.y);
  Serial.print(", Z: ");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.z);
  Serial.println(" m/s^2");

  Serial.print("Rotation X: ");
  Serial.print(g.gyro.x);
  Serial.print(", Y: ");
  Serial.print(g.gyro.y);
  Serial.print(", Z: ");
  Serial.print(g.gyro.z);
  Serial.println(" rad/s");
    // Read sensor data
    if (BLE.connected()) {
        float accelX = a.acceleration.x;
        float accelY = a.acceleration.y;
        float accelZ = a.acceleration.z;

        // Serial.print("X = "); Serial.print(accelX); Serial.print(", ");
        // Serial.print("Y = "); Serial.print(a.acceleration.y); Serial.print(", ");
        // Serial.print("Z = "); Serial.println(a.acceleration.z);

        // Gyroscope
        float gyroX = g.gyro.x;
        float gyroY = g.gyro.y;
        float gyroZ = g.gyro.z;


        // Convert float values to strings
        String accelXStr = String(accelX, 4);
        String accelYStr = String(accelY, 4);
        String accelZStr = String(accelZ, 4);
        String gyroXStr = String(gyroX, 3);
        String gyroYStr = String(gyroY, 3);
        String gyroZStr = String(gyroZ, 3);

       
        // accelCharacteristic.writeValue(("X: " + accelXStr).c_str(), ("X: " + accelXStr).length());
        // accelCharacteristic.writeValue(("Y: " + accelYStr).c_str(), ("Y: " + accelYStr).length());
        // accelCharacteristic.writeValue(("Z: " + accelZStr).c_str(), ("Z: " + accelZStr).length());
        String accelData = String(accelX) + " " + String(accelY) + " " + String(accelZ);
        accelCharacteristic.writeValue(accelData.c_str(), accelData.length() + 1);

        String gyroData = String(gyroX) + " " + String(gyroY) + " " + String(gyroZ);
        gyroCharacteristic.writeValue(gyroData.c_str(), gyroData.length() + 1);
        
    }
}


This is the python code used to receive the data.
from bleak import BleakClient
import time
import asyncio

# Replace with your device's address
DEVICE_ADDRESS = "74:4d:bd:98:8d:31" 
#b0:5f:ee:a7:d2:0f
#74:4d:bd:98:8d:31

# Service and characteristic UUIDs (same as Arduino code)
IMU_SERVICE_UUID = "b8b4e50d-f686-4757-918a-fcd2292782de"
ACCEL_CHAR_UUID = "85212279-0d50-4ca0-9a7e-730bdebf8e74"
GYRO_CHAR_UUID = "8c49379f-1cc9-46cc-94c3-38e12ef8e177"


async def main():
    async with BleakClient(DEVICE_ADDRESS) as client:
        print(f"Connected: {client.is_connected}")

        # Subscribe to both characteristics to receive notifications
        await client.start_notify(ACCEL_CHAR_UUID, on_accel_data_changed)
        await client.start_notify(GYRO_CHAR_UUID, on_gyro_data_changed)

        while True:
            # Stay connected and receive notifications
            await asyncio.sleep(1)


def on_accel_data_changed(sender, data):
    """Callback function for accelerometer data changes."""
    accel_values = [float(value) for value in data.decode('utf-8').split()]
    x_accel, y_accel, z_accel = accel_values  # Take the first three values

        # Print the individual values for X, Y, and Z axes
    print(f"Acceleration: {x_accel}, {y_accel}, {z_accel}")

def on_gyro_data_changed(sender, data):
    """Callback function for gyroscope data changes."""
    # Convert the received string into a list of float values
    gyro_values = [float(value) for value in data.decode('utf-8').split()]

    # Access the individual values for X, Y, and Z axes
    x_gyro, y_gyro, z_gyro = gyro_values

    # Print the individual values for X, Y, and Z axes
    print(f"Gyroscope: {x_gyro}, {y_gyro}, {z_gyro}")


asyncio.run(main())

I have the microcontroller connected to an external battery.
The code works perfectly when the microcontroller is directly connected to the laptop and the rate at which the data is being sent is fast. When I remove the direct connection, while the code is running, to the laptop the code continues to work but the rate at which the data is being sent is extremely slow. When I try to run the code without first having the direct connection to the laptop, it cannot find the MAC address of the microcontroller. Do I have to have the MCU directly connected to the laptop to find the MAC address?
I tried to use other external batteries of different voltage still the same thing. The battery I have connected right not is 3.7V 350Mah. I also tried using a power bank of 5V still no difference.
